# JSF rich tree + AJAX

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jsf-1.2

I have a rich tree and it contains few nodes. I have a checkbox beside each node. When I check a checkbox , checkbox pertaining to all the children needs to be checked and when I uncheck all the children have to be unchecked. I have the below code in my xhtml. In the backing bean , I set all the children to checked / unchecked based on the event. The tree is initially in "collapsed" mode. When I click on the checkbox and expand the node , I can see all the children being checked. But when I uncheck / check in expanded mode , the values aren't getting reflected in the child elements. Can you please help in letting me know what I am missing? Thanks.

```
    <rich:tree id="producttree" switchType="server"
        value="#updateProductBean.deviceServiceTreeRoot}" var="item">
        <rich:treeNode id="productnode">
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{item.selected}"
                rendered="#{item.value == null &amp;&amp; item.checkbox == true}"
                valueChangeListener="#{updateProductBean.submitUpdateProduct}">
                <f:attribute name="selectedProductId" id="selectedProductId"
                    value="#{item.paramID}" />
                <f:attribute name="selectedProductName" id="selectedProductName"
                    value="#{item.name}" />
                <a4j:support event="onclick" reRender="producttree,productnode">
                </a4j:support>
            </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.name}" rendered="#{item.value == null}" />
        </rich:treeNode>
    </rich:tree>
```

Comment: i'm guessing its reRendering problem. are you sure the tree is rebuild after the checkbox is checked?

Comment: Thanks for your response Ellie - I am not sure if the tree is being rebuilt completely. I added the boolean variable pertaining to the checkbox "selected" property as output text. This value is getting changed for the checkbox that I am checking - but not sure if the chold elements are getting re-rendered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wrapping your `h:selectBooleanCheckBox` inside a `a4j:outputPanel` tag then define an id name, then reRender this `a4j:outputPanel` on your `a4j:support` tag. If it is still not reRendered try putting `ajaxRendered="true"` on your `a4j:outputPanel` this will make it always updated for every ajax request.

Try this.

```
<rich:tree id="producttree" switchType="server"
                value="#updateProductBean.deviceServiceTreeRoot}" var="item">
                <rich:treeNode id="productnode">
                    <a4j:outputPanel id="panel" ajaxRendered="true">
                        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{item.selected}"
                            rendered="#{item.value == null &amp;&amp; item.checkbox == true}"
                            valueChangeListener="#{updateProductBean.submitUpdateProduct}">
                            <f:attribute name="selectedProductId" id="selectedProductId"
                                value="#{item.paramID}" />
                            <f:attribute name="selectedProductName" id="selectedProductName"
                                value="#{item.name}" />
                            <a4j:support event="onclick"
                                reRender="producttree,productnode, panel">
                            </a4j:support>
                        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                    </a4j:outputPanel>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.name}"
                        rendered="#{item.value == null}" />
                </rich:treeNode>
            </rich:tree>
```

Comment: Hi Ellie , tried this but this is not updating the checkboxes pertaining to child elements as well :(

Comment: try checking if the values of check box inside your nodes are updated, and the tree is rebuild correctly. Since it works on collapse mode.

Comment: I tried printing the values of the checkboxes inside the backing bean in the method (submitUpdateProduct) that gets invoked on check / uncheck. I am explicitly setting the values of all the child elements to true or false based on whether the parent checkbox is selected or not. The values are set properly. How can I ensure that the tree is rebuilt correctly? Thanks for all your help.

Comment: can you use change switchType="ajax"since you are using a4j:support it means that it is fire on ajax request. I'll try to create my own example based on your code and see if it works on mine.

Comment: Hi Ellie, the issue got fixed when I set the tree to null in the backing bean. The tree got rendered properly after that. Thanks a lot for your assistance!! BTW - gave you the bounty :)

Answer (score -1):

It Render the whole one level to which you click on tree so for that if you are having any ajax call then it will call the very first node and will skip for rest. The whole story is mapping the whole level.

Comment: You might consider rephrasing your answer for clarity and give an example to illustrate your point